# find the last saturday of given month

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

Does anyone knows how can i find the last saturday of given month? Assume that the given month is march.

Comment: Please, show what did you try so far. What can you do with SQL and what is the problem you've faced: how to get last, how to get Saturday, how to select single month, anything else?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function to do that. But you can create your own function.

```
create function last_weekday(p_date date, p_weekday int)
  returns date
as
$$
  select t.d::date
  from generate_series(date_trunc('month', p_date) + interval '1 month -8 day', 
                       date_trunc('month', p_date) + interval '1 month -1 day', interval '1 day') as t(d)
  where extract(isodow from d) = p_weekday
  order by t.d desc
  limit 1
$$
language sql
immutable
;
```

To get the value, pass in any date that is within the month you want to get the weekday for.

The idea is to generate a list of dates of the end of the given month extract those that fall on the given weekday (using ISO weekday numbers where 6 = Saturday) and return that value.

The expression `date_trunc('month', p_date) + interval '1 month -1 day'` returns the last day of the given month. Going back 7 days from that day will include each weekday at least once.

So to get the last Saturday of March, 2021 use:

```
select last_weekday(date '2021-03-07', 6);
```

---

Update: Gordon's answer inspired me to a different implementation:

`date_trunc('week', ..)` returns the monday of a week, subtracting 2 days will return the sunday:

```
create function last_saturday(p_date date)
  returns date
as
$$
  select date_trunc('week', date_trunc('month', p_date) + interval '1 month -1 day'):: date - 2;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name to get the last day of each month we can maybe do **EOMONTH**?

Comment: @tabacco: there is no `eomonth()` function Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Postgres starts day of week numbering on Sunday.  This actually makes it possible to find the last Saturday pretty simply:  Calculate the day of the week for the first day of the next month.  Subtract one more day than returned by `extract(dow)` from that date:

```
select (date_trunc('month', v.dte) + interval '1 month' -
        (extract(dow from date_trunc('month', v.dte + interval '1 month')) + 1) * interval '1 day'
       ) as last_saturday
from (values ('2020-10-01'::date)) v(dte)
```